# Rendering a template into a trusted HTML string [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS Toaster found [here](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster) to show ModelState errors from my API. You are able to pass AngularJS Toaster trusted HTML and I'd like to pass it HTML from a rendered template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modelStateErrors.html">
    <div>{{response}}</div>
</script>
```

Here's the code for popping up the toast:

```
app.service("errorService", ["$templateCache", "toaster", function ($templateCache, toaster) {
    this.catchErrors = function (response) {
        // Pass "response" to the template to render.
        toaster.pop("error", "", $templateCache.get("modelStateErrors.html"), 0, true);
    };
}]);
```

This code only produces the `<div>{{response}}</div>` as is, unparsed.

EDIT:
So I tried adding:

```
$compile($templateCache.get("modelStateErrors.html"))(response);
```

and I get this error message

```
Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you retrieve the template from the `$tempateCache`, you still need to compile it before writing it to the DOM:

[AngularJS: $compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)

Comment: So I tried $compile($templateCache.get("modelStateErrors.html"))(response); but I get Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element